# Publish PHP web on windows server 2016

Tags: iis, dns, xampp, subdomain, windows-server-2016

I would like to publish my web to Internet. I got access to virtual machine with windows server 2016 accessible throught IP with PORT.

On the server there are installed IIS (v10) and XAMPP. And for binding I cannot use port 80.

My web is using PHP and MySQL - that is installed via XAMPP.

My problem is that I do not know how to publish my the web on my subdomain - what I should set and where I should set that?

On my domain DNS manager I set up the subdomain with forwarding to IP address, which I use to connect to server. Is that okey? And what I should set on the binding page in IIS?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you unable to use port 80, or do not want to use 80 for some reason? Is this a new server, or is there existing sites / other things installed? Why do you have XAMPP and IIS installed? Also XAMPP is not designed for production systems, its a dev tool only for your local host.

Comment: @MisterSmith the owner of the server asked me not to use 80. It is new server. XAMPP and IIS because it was preinstaled from owner. What I should use instead of XAMPP?

Comment: Not using port 80 is a very strange limitation - can you clarify why? Using a none standard port for http will cause you issues.  Port 80 is the default port for http web traffic, or port 443 for secure http (ie https). You can host multiple sites on the same port (ie port 80 or 443) if hosted by the same webserver (but you cant have both iis and xxamp using port 80 and/ 443 at the same time). For production windows server I suggest iis, then install php extension and mariadb.